# Make gap even thickness?

Tags: modeling, snapping

I have two panels:
[image]
Between them is a uneven gap, in some places it is very narrow, in other places it is wide. How can I make it so that the gap is consistent width?

[image]

for testing on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this way:

1. Select both sides, <kbd>W</kbd> - Bridge Edge Loops. Enable Merge, set Factor to 0 (or 1);
2. Keep current selection, <kbd>V</kbd> to rip, then <kbd>RMB</kbd>;
3. Mesh > Edges > Edge Slide ( or <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>) to enable Edge Slide. <kbd>E</kbd> to toggle Even, if the current result is in a wrong way, then <kbd>F</kbd> to flip it (those are options shown on 3D View header).
4. Move to the expected position, then <kbd>LMB</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to apply changes.

[image]

**P.S.:** For the 3rd step, you can simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to bevel those edges. However, the normals for both islands are opposite in your case, you need to unify them before that.

Answer (score 3):

for a simple case like this you can deactivate the Solidify Modifier and use Remove Doubles to connect the 2 pieces.

Now select the edge that is where the gap was and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> to split the edge.  Now you can delete the faces to have the gap that was originally there.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this move the edge though, since the vertices would have to relocate?

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Some vertices are going to have to move no matter what, as they are currently uneven and you want them to be even.

Comment: My first thought was to shrink wrap a vertex group with a bit of an offset, and then apply the modifier. I like your solution better.